# Face that doesn't exist is being rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm not sure if this is the right place to be posting .blend files and asking people to help figure out problems with it, let me know if it's not allowed.

I am making this fire extinguisher, and I have run into a problem with the gauge portion. Blender is rendering a face that doesn't exist, if you look in solid mode there is no face:[image: Solid]

But, when rendered, a red face appears out of nowhere, I can't see the face in solid, or wireframe mode, I'm clueless as  to what is happening:[image]

Here is my .blend:
[image]
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually your face exists but you hid it, in Edit mode press alt H and it will appear

Comment: Oh my god. Noob here. Thanks a lot for the help!